# R move certain value while remain order from a dataframe of characters

Tags: r, na, reorderlist

I try to move from current dataframe while remaining orders, while it doesn't work as I wanted. tried to capture rest1, rest2 using grep works, but when I tried to reorder them, it gives vector with all the characters:(

the original DF looks like :

| ID | rank1 | rank2 | rank3 | rank4 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | rest1 | orange | grape | ... |
| 2 | rest2 | orange | rest1 | apple | ... |

so the expected table shall looks like, for each row, the "rest1"|"rest2" should be moved to last, df should looks like :

| ID | rank1 | rank2 | rank3 | rank4 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | orange | grape | ... | rest1 |
| 2 | orange | apple | ... | rest1 | rest2 |

I replace all the rest1 and rest2 with NA values, and move to the last columns. but the following code doesn't work.

df <- df %>% relocate(where(is.na), .after = last_col())

Comment: `relocate` is used to change column positions, whole columns at a time; it does not change the individual elements within each column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way,

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(
  t(apply(as.matrix(dat), 1,
          function(row) c(grep("^rest", row, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE),
                          grep("^rest", row, value = TRUE))))),
  names(dat))
#   ID  rank1  rank2 rank3 rank4 rank9
# 1  1  apple orange grape  <NA> rest1
# 2  2 orange  apple  <NA> rest2 rest1
```

Another way, a little simpler:

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(
  t(apply(as.matrix(dat), 1, function(row) row[order(grepl("^rest", row))]))),
  names(dat))
```

This should preserve the natural order within groups (e.g., first group is those that do not contain `"^rest"`).
You can add `sort(.)` if you need them in an order other than as it appears on each row.

**Note**: I'm inferring from the column names `rank#` that the columns themselves have relevance, in which case this operation is misordering your data. If you have to do this because it was ordered correctly at one point and now is malformed in the frame, I suggest you look into fixing the import process, and not rely on fixing it after the fact.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, rank1 = c("apple", "rest2"), rank2 = c("rest1", "orange"), rank3 = c("orange", "rest1"), rank4 = c("grape", "apple"), rank9 = c(NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))
```

Comment: thank you! I am not sure how function(row) works, does it work like column combining of values from "rest^" and non-"rest^" ? so by default grep returns (invert = False) ?

Comment: `row` is a `character` vector. The first `grep` returns the *value* of all strings that do not start with `"rest"`, and this includes the `NA`s (at the end). The second `grep` returns the *value* of all strings that start with `"rest"`. By `c(.)` concatenating them together, we should be assured now that the length of the new vector is the same as `length(row)`, with its element reordered.

Comment: See my alternative method, a *little* simpler.